# How to properly design application structure and separate application components?

Tags: architecture, scalability

I have following main components in application:

- Site and client panel
- Control panel (dashboard)
- Background service (billing tasks and messaging)
- API

My question is how to separate this components in application structure, so it would scale with increasing traffic, but also be maintainable and easy to continue developing after initial deployment?

Currently i'm trying to make it a single application and during runtime separate logic depending on startup configuration and routing by path and domain.

Another option i thought is to make separate application for each component, but to maintain four applications instead of one, with configurations, versions, shareable source (models, etc.), and continuing development will be a hell.

Another question is how large scale services like facebook design their service dashboards, control panels, or administrative parts of application.

Application is on RoR, but question is not dependent on language and framework.

I understand that topic is very large, but any help is very appreciated, at least - maybe some references to where do i start reading)

Comment: This really depends on what framework and language you use. try looking for "Single Responsibility". this is a design principle which basically says "classes should only be responsible for one thing". So a controller for example is responsible for returning a view only, not handling postdata from a form. Thats a responsibility for another class. There are many implementation for each language/framework.

Comment: @Nick I think you have a good point. Yes, every language has a separate way of implementing. But, the OP seems to ask much higher level question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 4 different applications this sounds like multiple modules separated by clearly defined interfaces that are interchangeable even at runtime.

*Each such separated piece then becomes one element of the modular architecture. Each piece should be isolated and should export and import well-defined interfaces.*

From here https://netbeans.org/project_downloads/usersguide/rcp-book-ch2.pdf

Bit old but still relevent.